# UICollectionView Cell Layout Issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'm working on a UICollectionView that contains cells with an image and a label. I've created a three-column flow layout.

However, I'm encountering an issue where the cells appear to be huge and out of proportion. When I inspect the app using the view debugger, I see that the constraints of the image view seem to be causing the issue. The image view's size grows beyond the cell size, and overlaps with other cells.

Here is the relevant code for my collection view setup and cell layout and a link to my project https://github.com/lexypaul13/Trending-Tv-Shows.git

```
// In the WeeklyViewController
func createThreeColumnFlowLayout() -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let width = view.bounds.width
    let padding: CGFloat = 12
    let minimumItemSpacing: CGFloat = 10
    let availableWidth = width - (padding * 2) - (minimumItemSpacing * 2)
    let itemWidth = availableWidth / 3

    let itemHeight = itemWidth * 1.3 // 1.3 is the aspect ratio, adjust based on your need

    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding)
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)

    return flowLayout
}

// In the TvCellCollectionViewCell 
private func set() {
    addSubview(tvImage)
    addSubview(tvName)
    
    tvImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tvName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let padding : CGFloat = 8
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tvImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
        tvImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
        tvImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
        tvImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tvImage.widthAnchor),
        tvName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tvImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
        tvName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
        tvName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
    ])
}
```

// In the cell
private func set() {
addSubview(tvImage)
addSubview(tvName)

```
tvImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tvName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let padding : CGFloat = 8

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tvImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
    tvImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
    tvImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
    tvImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tvImage.widthAnchor),
    tvName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tvImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
    tvName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
    tvName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
])
```

}

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In your `TvCellCollectionViewCell` class, you have:

```
private func set() {
    addSubview(tvImage)
    addSubview(tvName)
    // ...
```

You need to add the subviews to the cell's `contentView`:

```
private func set() {
    contentView.addSubview(tvImage)
    contentView.addSubview(tvName)
```